VBA frustration: Storing integers in an array but VBA thinks they are strings when referenced
In the code below I define the variable TP as an array. The first time TP = Array(Min + 5, Min + Div, Min + Div * 2, Min + Div * 3, Min + Div * 4, Max - 5, Max - 5). When TP(0) is referenced, vba sees it as an integer as "Min+5" was an integer. This makes sense. The second time TP = Array(ProbeTable(P, 4), ProbeTable(P, 4) + Div, ProbeTable(P, 5)). When TP(0) is referenced, vba see it as string even though "ProbeTable(P,4)" is an integer. Why is this?
Global I1, I2, I3, I4, Inputs As Variant
Global P1, P2, P3, P4, Probes As Variant
Global PRT, SCL, IC, PC, U, TP, BP, ITP, LL, UL, PTP, PT As Variant
Global MeterTable, ProbeTable As Variant
Global Min, Max, Dev As Integer
Global MI As Variant '(Meter Input #)
Sub Var()
    Set I1 = Range("I_1")
    Set I2 = Range("I_2")
    Set I3 = Range("I_3")
    Set I4 = Range("I_4")
    Inputs = Array(0, I1, I2, I3, I4)
    
    Set P1 = Range("P_1")
    Set P2 = Range("P_2")
    Set P3 = Range("P_3")
    Set P4 = Range("P_4")
    Probes = Array(0, P1, P2, P3, P4)
    
    PRT = Range("PRT")
    SCL = Range("SCL")
    IC = Range("IC").Value
    PC = Range("PC").Value
    U = Range("U")
    Set MeterTable = Range("MeterTable")
    Set ProbeTable = Range("ProbeTable")
    
    ITP = Array(0, "ITP_1", "ITP_2", "ITP_3", "ITP_4")
    LL = Array(0, "LL_1", "LL_2", "LL_3", "LL_4")
    UL = Array(0, "UL_1", "UL_2", "UL_3", "UL_4")
    
    PTP = Array(0, "PTP_1", "PTP_2", "PTP_3", "PTP_4")
    PT = Array(0, "PT_1", "PT_2", "PT_3", "PT_4")
End Sub

Function CtoF(T) 'Converts deg C to deg F.
    CtoF = (T * 1.8) + 32
End Function
Function CtoFTol(T)  'Converts tolerances in deg C to deg F.
    CtoFTol = T * 1.8
End Function
Function FtoC(T) 'Converts deg F to deg C.
    FtoC = (T - 32) / 1.8
End Function
Function FtoCTol(T) 'Converts tolerances in deg F to deg C.
    FtoCTol = T / 1.8
End Function

Sub Cal()

    Call Var
    
    'Populates the meter indication test section of the checklist. Including testpoints, and lower and upper limit tolerances.
    For I = 1 To IC
        'Determines seven testpoints covering the span of the digital thermometer.
        Min = Application.Min(MeterTable(I, 3), MeterTable(I, 7), MeterTable(I, 11))
        Max = Application.Max(MeterTable(I, 4), MeterTable(I, 8), MeterTable(I, 12))
        Div = Abs(Max - Min) / 5
        TP = Array(Min + 5, Min + Div, Min + Div * 2, Min + Div * 3, Min + Div * 4, Max - 5, Max - 5)
        ReDim TolPer(0 To 6), TolCon(0 To 6), TPTol(0 To 6), TPLL(0 To 6), TPUL(0 To 6)
        
        'Determines the LL and UL for each test point.
        For A = 0 To 6
            'Rounds test points to the nearest multiple of 5.
            If TP(A) < 0 Then
                TP(A) = Application.MRound(TP(A), -5)
            Else
                TP(A) = Application.MRound(TP(A), 5)
            End If
            
            'Determines PC and TC for each test point.
            If TP(A) >= MeterTable(I, 3) And TP(A) <= MeterTable(I, 4) Then
                TolPer(A) = MeterTable(I, 5)
                TolCon(A) = MeterTable(I, 6)
            ElseIf TP(A) >= MeterTable(I, 7) And TP(A) <= MeterTable(I, 8) Then
                TolPer(A) = MeterTable(I, 9)
                TolCon(A) = MeterTable(I, 10)
            ElseIf TP(A) >= MeterTable(I, 11) And TP(A) <= MeterTable(I, 12) Then
                TolPer(A) = MeterTable(I, 13)
                TolCon(A) = MeterTable(I, 14)
            End If
            
            'Calculates the tolerance for each test point ±[TP+TC].
            TPTol(A) = Abs(TP(A) * TolPer(A) / 100) + TolCon(A)
            
            'Calculates the LL and UL for each test point.
            If A < 6 Then
                TPLL(A) = TP(A) - TPTol(A)
                TPUL(A) = TP(A) + TPTol(A)
            ElseIf A = 6 And U = "C" Then
                TP(A) = CtoF(TP(A))
                TPLL(A) = TP(A) - CtoFTol(TPTol(A))
                TPUL(A) = TP(A) + CtoFTol(TPTol(A))
            ElseIf A = 6 And U = "F" Then
                TP(A) = FtoC(TP(A))
                TPLL(A) = TP(A) - FtoCTol(TPTol(A))
                TPUL(A) = TP(A) + FtoCTol(TPTol(A))
            End If
            
            'Rounds the LL and UL to two decimal places.
            TPLL(A) = Application.RoundUp(TPLL(A), 2)
            TPUL(A) = Application.RoundDown(TPUL(A), 2)
        Next A
        
        'Pastes the testpoints, LL, and UL limit values to the checklist.
        Range(ITP(I)) = Application.Transpose(TP)
        Range(LL(I)) = Application.Transpose(TPLL)
        Range(UL(I)) = Application.Transpose(TPUL)
    Next I
    
    For P = 1 To PC
        'Determines three test points for the probe/meter system test.
        Div = Abs(ProbeTable(P, 5) - ProbeTable(P, 4)) / 2
        ReDim TP(0 To 2)
        TP = Array(ProbeTable(P, 4), ProbeTable(P, 4) + Div, ProbeTable(P, 5))
        
        'Determines which meter input matches the probe type.
        MI = ProbeTable(P, 2)
        ReDim TolPer(0 To 2), TolCon(0 To 2), TPTol(0 To 2)
        
        'Determines the system test tolerance for each test point.
        For B = 0 To 2
            'Rounds test points to the nearest multiple of 5.
            If TP(B) < 0 Then
                TP(B) = Application.Fixed(Application.MRound(TP(B), -5), 3)
            Else
                TP(B) = Application.Fixed(Application.MRound(TP(B), 5), 3)
            End If
                
            Min = Application.Max(Application.Min(MeterTable(MI, 3), MeterTable(MI, 7), MeterTable(MI, 11)), ProbeTable(P, 11))
            Max = Application.Min(Application.Max(MeterTable(MI, 4), MeterTable(MI, 8), MeterTable(MI, 12)), ProbeTable(P, 12))
            
            'Determines if the probe range is within the meter and ASME range for that TC type.
            If TP(B) > Max Or TP(B) < Min Then
                MsgBox "Probe" & P & " is out of range!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
                Exit For
            End If
'           Determines the system test tolerance TCTol ±[TP+TC] for each test point.
            If TP(B) >= MeterTable(MI, 3) And TP(B) <= MeterTable(MI, 4) Then
                TolPer(B) = MeterTable(MI, 5)
                TolCon(B) = MeterTable(MI, 6)
            ElseIf TP(B) >= MeterTable(MI, 7) And TP(B) <= MeterTable(MI, 8) Then
                TolPer(B) = MeterTable(MI, 9)
                TolCon(B) = MeterTable(MI, 10)
            ElseIf TP(A) >= MeterTable(MI, 11) And TP(B) <= MeterTable(MI, 12) Then
                TolPer(B) = MeterTable(MI, 13)
                TolCon(B) = MeterTable(MI, 14)
            End If
            TPTol(B) = Abs(TP(B) * TolPer(B) / 100) + TolCon(B)

            If U = "F" Then: TP(B) = FtoC(TP(B))

            'Determines the probe tolerance TP or TC for each test point.
            If TP(B) < 0 Then
                TolPer(B) = Abs(ProbeTable(P, 8) * TP(B) / 100)
                TolCon(B) = ProbeTable(P, 7)
            Else
                TolPer(B) = Abs(ProbeTable(P, 10) * TP(B) / 100)
                TolCon(B) = ProbeTable(P, 9)
            End If

            If U = "F" Then: TP(B) = CtoF(TP(B))

            'Determines the probe tolerance, either TP or TC for each test point.
            If TolPer(B) > TolCon(B) Then
                If U = "F" Then TPTol(B) = TPTol(B) + CtoFTol(TolPer(B))
                If U = "C" Then TPTol(B) = TPTol(B) + TolPer(B)
            Else
                If U = "F" Then TPTol(B) = TPTol(B) + CtoFTol(TolCon(B))
                If U = "C" Then TPTol(B) = TPTol(B) + TolCon(B)
            End If
                TPTol(B) = Application.Fixed(Application.RoundDown(TPTol(B), 3), 3)

                'Formats the system test test points and tolerances.
                TP(B) = "TI Indication @ " & TP(B) & "°" & U
                TPTol(B) = "±" & TPTol(B) & " of standard"
        Next B
        
        'Pastes the system test testpoints and tolerances to the checklist.
        Range(PTP(P)) = Application.Transpose(TP)
        Range(PT(P)) = Application.Transpose(TPTol)
    Next P
End Sub

Why does vba make TP(0) a string even though I stored an integer as TP(0)? At the line "If TP(B) > Max Or TP(B) < Min Then" even though TP(B) = "0.000", it should be 0 not a string, it does not meet the conditions even though it is greater than Max and less than Min because TP(0) is qual to "0.000" not 0. If I use the CINT() function and make the line If CINT(TP(B)) > Max Or CINT(TP(B)) < Min Then instead the code works but I shouldn't have to do this as "ProbeTable(P,4)" is an integer not a string. VBA assumed the values were integers the first time I defined TP why not the second? What am I missing. I included the entire code below. Thank you in advance!

Global Min, Max, Dev As Integer only Dev is integer...

Just a side comment: Global Min, Max, Dev As Integer this declares Dev as an Integer but Min and Max are Variants. You seem to be using variants a lot here.

Side note: what is your reasoning for using Variant over Range for I1, I2, I3, I4 and P1, P2, P3, P4 and MeterTable and ProbeTable?

@Top Thank you! Apparently only a few versions of vba let you define variables the way I did.  Additionally my problem has been solved but Im not really sure why.  Even though Min and Max were variants excel viewed them as integers. I have to keep TP as a variant or says its not defined correctly. I'm using a lot of variants because the ranges contain both strings and integers. Also is there a down side to using variants?

@Big this has been corrected, thank you! I'm not really sure why using range over varaint is better but the code works both ways.

The ones that it recognizes as integers all have math in their assignment, that's probably why it is putting them as integers. TP needs to be a variant because you're storing variants in it, at least the one that is an array of arrays.

The downside of using variant for everything is the issue you just encountered along with it generally being less readable than knowing the type something should be and it has worse optimization since variants use more resources.

@BrianBodzenta You wrote "only a few versions of vba let you define variables the way I did.". What versions of VBA allow that? I've not run across any that do.
